# Can I fill Django form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, django

So I have an input field, but want to fill it in with a dropdown item. I figured I'd have to do it with jQuery, but have no idea how. Here's my code :

```
<span class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn menial-buttons dropdown-toggle" id="cat-dropdown-input" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span> Category</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <button class="dropdown-item" id="cat-1">Book</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" id="cat-2">Drink</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" id="cat-3">Play</button>
    </div>
</span>
<div class="field">
    <div class="input-category">{{form.category}}</div>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery code. I'm not very familiar with jQuery.

```
$('.dropdown-item').click(function() {
  var thisCat = $(this).text();
  $('#id_category').html(thisCat);
});
```

*The `id` of the form field is `#id_category`.
Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: if the buttons are inside a form, you are maybe triggering the form before jquery set the "data". you coud try add type="button" or in jquery use `e.preventDetault()`

Comment: If the id is **#id_category** you need to escape it: $.escapeSelector('#id_category') or you can write directly: "#\\#id_category".  Try: $('#\\#id_category').html(thisCat)

Comment: @gaetanoM So would the code be ```$.escapeSelector('#id_category').html(thisCat);```??

Comment: no. The correct one is:  $('#' + $('#id_category')).html(thisCat);  For details take a look to [jQuery.escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/)